# How can I reuse spark SQL view/table across multiple AWS EMR steps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am submitting multiple steps (concurrency - 1) to AWS EMR cluster by command - 'spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn <>' one after other.

1. In first step I'm reading for S3 and creating dataframe out of it. I'm registering this dataframe as spark SQL table/view using createGlobalTempView
2. In second step I'm trying to access table/view in my spark SQL query (tried with global_temp... as well), but getting table/view not found exception.

What I am missing? Doesn't createGlobalTempView should be accessible across multiples sessions? Or sessions and steps are different things? How I can achieve this?

Comment: I want to do this because I've to run multiple queries on same S3 data set. So as per me it would be better if I read once from S3 and keep it in memory (somewhat spilled to disk if required) and thereafter run those multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

One `step` in EMR is like a single spark application and the lifetime of the view created using `createGlobalTempView` is tied to this Spark application.

The same can be seen in the pyspark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createGlobalTempView.html?highlight=createglobaltempview#)

And yes `session` and `steps` are different other things.

A `step` in EMR submits a job that creates a spark application and once the step finishes executing, all the temp views created within it are gone.

The same can be verified by adding this small line of code in your each-step script.

```
print(spark.sparkContext.getApplicationId())
```

- spark mentioned above is sparkSession.

Both the steps that you have executed will have different applications.
There can be multiple `SparkSessions` associated with a spark application and can be only one `SparkContext` per application.

To achieve this you can create a temp table in `Hive` like:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("table-name")
```

and
can use this table in the next `step` as input data.

```
df= spark.sql("select * from table-name")
```

or
if you don't want to create a temp table another way is to include your transformation sqls on the same script.